# How to access a model to home view index.cshtml file in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am completely new to ASP.NET Core and following along the Microsoft's documentation and developing a simple web application. Sorry, if the question is not clear.

I have created a model, view and controller called `Broadcast`. This model has a field called live. I would like to access this model to home view's `index.cshtml` file which is a separate view.

I have tried including `Broadcast` view on the top at `index.cshtml` file home view

```
@model IEnumerable<SideCar.Models.Broadcast>
```

When I am accessing the model using `@foreach` I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Could you please guide, what should I learn to access the model into a different view? Thank you.

Here is the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SideCar.Data;
using SideCar.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SideCar.Controllers
{
    public class BroadcastController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public BroadcastController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Broadcast> objList = _db.Boradcast;
            return View(objList);
        }
    }
}
```

and model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SideCar.Models
{
    public class Broadcast
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BroadcastHeading { get; set; }        
        public string BroadcastDesc1 { get; set; }
        public string BroadcastDesc2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActiveDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }        
        public string Live { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on ` IEnumerable<Broadcast> objList = _db.Boradcast;` and check if `objList` is null or not. You should have a conditional, in your front end, before your foreach loop to check if there are any elements in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Change you index action to this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var objList = _db.Set<Broadcast>().ToArray();
            return View(objList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:

1. add `@if (Model != null){}` outside `@foreach` in view
2. use

   ```
   IEnumerable<Broadcast> objList = _db.Boradcast.ToList();
   ```

   to replace

   ```
   IEnumerable<Broadcast> objList = _db.Boradcast;
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Still null object. Page loads fine but no data is flowing because if condition is restricting it.

`code` public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Broadcast> objList = _db.Boradcast.ToList();
            return View(objList);
        }

@if (Model != null) 
{
    @foreach (var obj in Model)
    { 
        <h2>test</h2>
    }
} `code`

Comment: Have you checked your ` _db.Boradcast.ToList（)`,maybe it doesn't have data.

Comment: There is one record in the table and a different view which share the same name as the controller and model shows the data correctly.